# Is it possible to hide the tabbar when a button is pressed to allow a full screen view of the content?

Tags: iphone, uitableview, uitabbarcontroller, tabbar

I have a UITabBar in the detail view of my navigation based application.  I am storing text and images in a tableview and would like the user to be able to tap on a cell to hide the navigation controller and the tabbar for full screen viewing of the content.

I found this code for hiding the top bars, but it does not seem as easy to hide the tabbar.

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarHidden:YES animated:YES];
 [self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:YES animated:YES];
```

Does anyone know how to do this?

This code does not work to hide the tabBar once the view is already loaded.

```
  yourTabViewController.hidesBottomBarWhenPushed = YES;
```

---

This is the code I found.  Seems to only work when the view is loaded though, so it can't be used to hide the tabbar once it has already appeared. I'm still struggling to make this work.  Please help!!!

```
    self.tabBarController.tabBar.hidden = YES;
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The best workaround I have found is to change the view size so that it covers the tabbar. Here's my code for hiding the statusBar, navBar, and tabBar when a row is selected:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

AppDelegate *appDelegate = (AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];

if (appDelegate.navigationController.navigationBar.hidden == NO)
{
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarHidden:YES animated:YES];
    [appDelegate.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:YES animated:YES];

    [UIView beginAnimations:@"HideTabbar" context:nil];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:.2];
    self.view.frame = CGRectMake(0,0,320,480);
    [UIView commitAnimations];
}
if (appDelegate.navigationController.navigationBar.hidden == YES)
{
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarHidden:NO animated:YES];
    [appDelegate.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:NO animated:YES];

    [UIView beginAnimations:@"ShowTabbar" context:nil];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:.2];
    self.view.frame = CGRectMake(0,0,320,368);
    [UIView commitAnimations];
}   
}
```

Answer (score 26):

There's a built-in way to do this:

`self.hidesBottomBarWhenPushed = YES;`

But you have to do this BEFORE the view is pushed. This is how you might want to use that:

```
ChildViewController* childVC = [[ChildViewController alloc] init];
childVC.hidesBottomBarWhenPushed = YES;
[self.navigationController pushViewController:childVC animated:YES];
[childVC release];
```

Comment: Or just set self.hidesBottomBarWhenPushed = YES inside the init method of the controller

Comment: What if I want to do that with the root viewController at the top of the stack?

Answer (score 6):

My solution:

```
// Hide tab bar animated
CATransition *animation = [CATransition animation];
[animation setType:kCATransitionFade];
[[self.view.window layer] addAnimation:animation forKey:@"layerAnimation"]; 
[self.tabBarController.tabBar setHidden:YES];

// Display tab bar animated
CATransition *animation = [CATransition animation];
[animation setType:kCATransitionFade];
[[self.view.window layer] addAnimation:animation forKey:@"layerAnimation"]; 
[self.tabBarController.tabBar setHidden:NO];
```

You have to add `#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>`

Comment: This worked wonderfully! You can set "no bottom bar" in your storyboard or interface builder right panel for the controller that you are modifying to get a more accurate idea of where the interface elements would end up once you hide the tabbar

Comment: This hides the tab bar, but leaves an ugly black space

Answer (score 3):

I´ve found one answer to this issue, is very simple and effective.

The solution is to set the option **"Hides Bottom Bar on Push"** in ALL VIEWS, VIEW CONTROLLERS and TAB BAR CONTROLLERS of your app.

You can do this in IB or by code anyway.

Hope you this helps everyone...

Answer (score 0):

In order to adjust the size of your window, you first need to select the option of NONE in the status bar field, under your Attributes tab, of your Inspector window. Interface Builder will then let you change the size of your window.

Answer (score 0):

In case any one needs the MonoTouch version os this cool little trick. (thanks!)

```
    // Method implementations
    static void hideTabBar (UITabBarController tabbarcontroller)
    {
        UIView.Animate(0.4, delegate() { 
            foreach(UIView view in tabbarcontroller.View.Subviews)
            {
                if(view.GetType()==typeof(UITabBar))
                    view.Frame=new  RectangleF(view.Frame.X, 480, view.Frame.Size.Width, view.Frame.Size.Height);
                else 
                    view.Frame=new  RectangleF(view.Frame.X, view.Frame.Y, view.Frame.Size.Width, 480);
            }
        });
    }

    static void showTabBar (UITabBarController tabbarcontroller)
    {
        UIView.Animate(0.4, delegate() { 
            foreach(UIView view in tabbarcontroller.View.Subviews)
            {
                if(view.GetType()==typeof(UITabBar))
                    view.Frame=new  RectangleF(view.Frame.X, 367, view.Frame.Size.Width, view.Frame.Size.Height);
                else 
                    view.Frame=new  RectangleF(view.Frame.X, view.Frame.Y, view.Frame.Size.Width, 367);
            }
        });
    }
```