# In Tab-based iPhone app, how to hide the tabbar in some ViewControllers?

Tags: iphone, uitabbarcontroller

I've an Tab-bar based iPhone app.

the app consiste of 2 tabs.
Each tab has a navigation controller with 3 ViewControllers.

How to prevent the TabBar from being displayed in one of the ViewControllers (because it already has its own TabBar navigation)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found this a, credit the original postert:

[Is it possible to hide the tabbar when a button is pressed to allow a full screen view of the content?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1209582/is-it-possible-to-hide-the-tabbar-when-a-button-is-pressed-to-allow-a-full-scree)

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

AppDelegate *appDelegate = (AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];

if (appDelegate.navigationController.navigationBar.hidden == NO)
{
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarHidden:YES animated:YES];
    [appDelegate.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:YES animated:YES];

    [UIView beginAnimations:@"HideTabbar" context:nil];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:.2];
    self.view.frame = CGRectMake(0,0,320,480);
    [UIView commitAnimations];
}
if (appDelegate.navigationController.navigationBar.hidden == YES)
{
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarHidden:NO animated:YES];
    [appDelegate.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:NO animated:YES];

    [UIView beginAnimations:@"ShowTabbar" context:nil];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:.2];
    self.view.frame = CGRectMake(0,0,320,368);
    [UIView commitAnimations];
}   
}
```

Comment: `self.hidesBottomBarWhenPushed = YES;` Thanks!